# Not sure how to write a certain mongodb query

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm working on a ruby project and using mongodb. I'm saving shows in the databses with their start and end times. I'm trying to get a result of the current show (according to the time now) and the show following that. Here is my code:

```
def get_current_and_next_schedule(channel, time = Time.now)
  end_of_day = _get_end_of_day(time)
  Schedule.all(
    :start_time => { '$gte' => time.utc },
    :end_time   => { '$lte' => end_of_day.utc },
    :show_id    => { '$in' => Show.all(:channel_id => channel.id).collect { |s| s.id } },
    :order      => :start_time,
    :limit      => 2
  )
end
```

If I have two shows with times 3:00-4:00 and 4:00-5:00 They should be in the returned result if I query the database at 3:30. But using the above code, only the 4:00-5:00 show will be in the result. I know this is because I check for '$gte' => time.utc
How do I fix this query so that it includes the current show if the start time has passed but the show hasn't ended?

Comment: the end of day part falls apart and you would only get one result if your first show spans two days or ends at midnight (I am assuming what happens in that method).

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem if a show ends past midnight. It won't be included in the results

Answer (score 0):

where `end_time` is **greater than** current time and `end_time` is **less than or equal to** `end_of_day`. So may be

```
:end_time   => { '$gt' => time.utc },
:end_time   => { '$lte' => end_of_day.utc }
```